# Screenshot from hidden html video element

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to take a screenshot of a hidden element using canvas, but the image source is empty.

Here is my screenshot function:

```
function getScreenshot(videoEl) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = videoEl.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = videoEl.clientHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(videoEl, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();

    image.width = canvas.width;
    image.height = canvas.height;

    return image;
}
```

and in my html file I have this video tag

```
 <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
```

and css

```
video {
    display: none;
}
```

If I remove `display:none` and the video element is visible, then the image has data.

I've done lots of searching but cant find anything on this matter, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!